# Do non sticky LTO barcode labels exist?

Tags: lto

I don't rip off old LTO labels that often, but it is very annoying when I do have to do it. Is there a stickerless solution? Perhaps stick on clear sleeves or plastic tabs that hold removable labels?

Answer (score 10):

A dab of rubbing alcohol on a paper towel usually takes the sticker right off in my experience. Or, just put the new sticker right over the old one.

I think you may be overthinking this.

Food for thought: Do you even really *want* a solution where it's easy to take a barcode label off? If you inventory your tapes entirely by barcode and you need to restore, what do you do if the "easy to remove" label has been knocked off of two of your tapes in transit? You've just complicated your restore immensely.

Comment: Labels peeling of when not wanted is a major pita. I had a label coming off once in a Magstar library. It ended up in one of the tape-drives. Luckily not with the sticky side against anything so I was able to suck it out with a vacuum-cleaner. (Not enough space to get my fingers in. And the angle made it impossible to get at it with pincers.) Since that day I check religiously if new labels stick really well.

Comment: @Tonny I didn't even *think* of the label coming off inside of the robot. That would be terrible. Imagine a weekend set of fulls failing because a label is stuck in the loader?

Comment: I imagine a label can come off easily when intended or not so easily when not intended. (e.g. zippers, velcro, clasps on the side of memory modules, etc.) Whether or not someone or some company has crafted this solution, I don't know... :)